# How can i use getResource(...) to grab the .png file from resources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfE3F.png)

This is one of things I have tried:
In class 'EditScreenController.java':

```
Button placeholderEdit = new Button();
Image pencil = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("pencil.png"));

placeholderEdit.setGraphic(new ImageView(pencil));
```

Result:

```
 Input stream must not be null
```

I know it's something super simple, and yet I have already tried multiple things :( . Would highly appreciate a working answer.

Enjoy the rest of your day!

Comment: Have you tried "img/pencil.png"? I think it doesn't work because you get files from the resources folder but the image itself in the nested folder.

Comment: Thanks for the respond, i tried "img/pencil.png", but that one didn't work.

"/img/pencil.png" did the job tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Image pencil = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img/pencil.png"));
```

This solved my issue.